# How to check if a drive has an MBR?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, mbr, disk-cloning

I cloned my drive. Then I wanted to select that as boot device, but it didn't show up in BIOS.

[This forum post](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/281798-32-doesn-show-boot-devices-bios) says it's because the MBR was not copied.

So how do I verify that the MBR was copied? In other words, how can I check that a disk is bootable in Windows 7?

Comment: How did you clone the drive?  Did you only clone the primary partition?  A direct 1:1 on the drive should have copied the MBR.

Comment: I clone the system partition only. Using acronis true image.

Comment: Just cloning the system partition did not clone your MBR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the drive won't boot, there's something wrong with the MBR or it's not there, so that's your "verification". However, the command `bootrec.exe /ScanOs` should display the list of active records the MBR. If there are none, then again, it's either missing or corrupt.

[Kruug's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/559505/how-to-check-if-an-ssd-has-an-mbr#comment682058_559505) is correct in that if you improperly cloned the drive (for instance, only cloned one partition), then the MBR might not have copied. To successfully clone a bootable drive, you have to do a 1-to-1 clone, or use a tool that allows you to clone the MBR and selected partitions. Personally, I use [Macrium Reflect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx&ei=zSQxUZqMCcu40AGZlYH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNG0f_QPhbenn0BJ2ONmmZgr1fsSNg&sig2=5caFJbZ5zdSZBgLGrwSnJA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.dmQ).

As for repairing it, using a Windows boot disk:

1. On the install Windows splash screen, click "Repair your computer"

   [image]
2. After a short hardware scan, in the "System Recovery Options screen", click the bottom option for command prompt:

   [image]
3. In the command prompt, enter the following commands (each should follow with an "Operation was successful"):

   ```
   bootrec.exe /FixMbr
   bootrec.exe /FixBoot
   ```

Source: [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,10036.html)

Comment: If an editing guru could somehow figure out why the numbering in my post won't sequence, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: I have 2 drives. Which drive will that fix? Should I cd to the ssd drive first? Also I want my ssd to be the new c.

Comment: How to check if the hard disk already have MBR?

Comment: @JimThio To be safe, you could temporarily remove the drive that doesn't have the operating system on it.

Comment: Actually I got everything working. I install windows and simply overwrite the new installation with previous system volume. Solve problem.